# Using ETag as database lock in REST API

Tags: api, rest, http, http-headers, etag

Is there any good reason not to take my optimistic lock value from my database table and use it as a weak ETag directly in my REST API? It seems like it works be a perfect fit but I'm not sure I've ever seen it done.

Likewise using the Last-Modified header to convey the last updated date of the resource.